# How can i display a Text on all cell day in Full calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I want to display a text on every cell in full calendar but im always getting that long bar by default. can anyone know how to do that?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendarOutput');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth'
        },
        displayEventTime:false,
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        selectable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        eventSources:[
           {
           url:'http://localhost/servrevo_web/booking/getDate',
           allDayDefault: 'true',
           color: '#02a3bd',  
           textColor: 'black'
           },
           {
           url:'http://localhost/servrevo_web/booking/getBooking',
           color: '#87a900',  
           textColor: 'black'
           }
           ] 

        });  
        opts.dayRender= function(date, cell) {
        cell.append('<i class="fc-content" aria-hidden="true">Hello</i>');   
        }
     $('#calendarEl').fullCalendar(opts);
```

});

Comment: long bar .... ??

Comment: i mean when you are using "start" and "end" it will look like a line, consuming the days between the start and end. what i want is, every day cell would have a same text.

Comment: Better show your code so that we could reproduce the issue. Or create working snippet (`[<>]` in editor).

Comment: `calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar` and `$('#calendarEl').fullCalendar` ...you seem to be mixing up syntax for fullCalendar v3 and v4...which version are you using? You can't just swap between the syntaxes like that, the two versions are [very different](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3) . I'm surprised you don't actually have a JavaScript error in your Console?

Comment: And if you want to specify the dayRender on your calendar, you can just add it directly as an option. Not sure why you'd bother to declare it separately like that.

Comment: im using v4, The code below is the example on docs, i cant understand the v4 of dayRender. So im using the code of v3 but its not working even though im trying to change it to v4 any help :(

Comment: what is the correct syntax? i'm so confused on what is the right implementation of dayRender.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayRender - what part is confusing you exactly? You can attach your element to the `dayRenderInfo.el` - as mentioned in the documentation. But it's a HTML element instead of a jQuery object, that's the main difference.

Comment: Can you give me some example code for displaying names in all day cell using dayrender?

Comment: I added an answer below. It's hardly any different to what you're doing now, it's just using the different object structure in v4, and not using jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have tried to use the syntax for fullCalendar v3 instead of v4. This will never work, since they are implemented very differently.

However, using the `dayRender` callback specifically in v4 is actually quite similar to v3, but the main differences are that you receive one object as input to the function, which then contains other objects representing the date, the HTML element to modify, and the current view. And the HTML element is a native DOM element object, not a jQuery object (since v4 no longer needs or uses jQuery).

This should work for you:

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
    /*.... then all your other options, and then....*/
    dayRender: function(dayRenderInfo) {
      dayRenderInfo.el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<i class="fc-content" aria-hidden="true">Hello</i>');
    }
});
```

Documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/dayRender

Comment: Thank you, i'll try implementing this sample

Comment: Note, in v5, `dayRender` has been replaced by "Day-Cell Render Hooks".

See documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/day-cell-render-hooks and v4 to v5 changelog: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v4